# Can't find 'path' in worker using Electron & Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, electron

My electron app uses a worker to compile WASM in the background (through worker-loader). However, I get the following error when running it:[image]

How would I solve this error? It looks like the module is trying to use `path`, so I've added the `path` fallback in Webpack config:

[image]

However, this didn't fix my issue

**worker.js**

```js
import { Essentia, EssentiaWASM } from 'essentia.js';
let essentia = new Essentia(EssentiaWASM);

self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  console.log(essentia.version);
})
```